# Is it safe to delete crossdomain.xml now that Flash is no longer supported

Tags: flash, content-security-policy

A website I have contributed to has a `crossdomain.xml` file live.

Through my personal Googling it seems that this file is related exclusively related to [cross domain permissions for Adobe Flash](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/cross-domain-xml-for-streaming.html).

As [Flash is no longer supported](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) by Adobe nor by major browsers - is it safe to assume that this file can be deleted without causing any problems?